# How do I fix streaky Krylon High Heat paint on brass fireplace detail?

Tags: fireplace, repainting, oil-based-paint, spray-paint

I attempted to paint my brass fireplace detail with Krylon High Heat paint. It’s 3 sided with doors that have a brass strip on the top and bottom. A couple sections ended up streaky.
Can I sand it and repaint it? Can I sand it and spray paint it? How do I fix it?
It seems like an oil based paint instead of the latex paint I’m used to working with. [image][image]

Comment: What steps did you take to get where you are now? How did you prepare the surface? How many coats did you apply? Did you use primer? How long has it been since you painted the brass? Can you post pictures?

Comment: Great questions @Greg, plus I'll add how was the original paint applied (spray, brush or roll-on). I assume what you painted was metal and surface prep was required. Don't do anything more until the paint has dried per the manufacturer and you've answered our questions. Also, by "streaky" do you mean uneven color and/or it has drips?

Comment: I cleaned it, lightly sanded with fine grit sandpaper, and wiped off the dust. I didn’t use primer. I used 3 coats of the black paint and applied with a brush. The first one seemed really watery and didn’t spread consistently. Then I had difficulty spreading it properly at the corners but it got tacky faster than I anticipated. I did this just yesterday so it’s still lightly tacky. I’ll try to post a couple pictures.